# How can I get web sockets to be robust with Apache Mina?

Tags: java, websocket, red5, mina

I am trying to build an html5/websocket based poker client. I have a game server written in Java, and I've pulled a web socket handling chunk of code from Red5 game server (java based) and I'm also using Apache Mina.

My game server is working fine with java applet based clients.

Web socket integration works, but it's not robust and the server regularly thinks the connection is dropped, and so no more messages get sent to the client. The client can still send messages on the socket however, which I can see in the game server logs.

Perhaps you can't help with this specific problem, but if not, perhaps you could recommend a better architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Create a keep-alive service to ping your clients every x seconds. This will keep the browsers from dropping the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I've actually solved this by switching to [netty](http://netty.io). Netty has proper web socket support and so I did not need to pull bits of code from other projects, and so far it seems very robust.